# how to call a specific php function if got two php function using a href

Tags: php, html

```
//Login.php
function display_login_form(){
   //..Code
}

function handle_login(){
   //..Code
}

-------------------------------------------------
//AddSubject.php
//No include any header
function handle_addsub_form(){
    //..Some code
    echo <<<SUCCESSRESPONSE
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>New Subject record inserted</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/mycss.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1 id="white">Creation of Subject</h1>
            <h3 id="white">Created entry for subject $subjectcode $title</h3>

            <br/>
            <a href="XXXXXX">//<=== go to first php function handle_login()
                <span id="white">Home</span>
            </a>
        </body>  
    </html>
SUCCESSRESPONSE;
}
```

From my code above, i assume everybody understand my question right?
how i go to specific function only

Because if i just input 
     
It will just go to the first function and i would like to go only specific function and ignore the rest of it. it's possible to do it?

Comment: I like to read the question before I look at the code. You you mind spelling it out for me, please?

Comment: nurdglaw  I think I understand what she's asking.

She needs to check $_POST or $_GET to check whether the form has been submitted, and determine what to show based on that

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the form was submitted.
Something like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){
    handle_login();    
} else {
    display_login_form();
}
?>
```

Comment: You can call any function. Just change the function calls.

Comment: i no need to include the header file right?
just do it like yours ?

Comment: You should edit your question to be a bit more specific on what you want to achieve.

Comment: editted. so what should i place inside my <a href> over there?

Comment: "Login.php"
Login.php should declare the two functions.
Then with some logic you can determine what function to call.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you don't "go to" a function, you call it. Your PHP code needs some logic to know which function to call. You can add query string parameters, use a form, there are many ways. You have to write some logic though, it's not a built in feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the name of function you want to execute and put it in switch statement.

```
$fn = $_REQUEST['fn'];

switch($fn){
   case "handleLogin":
    handleLogin();
   break;
   default:
    echo "function not found";
   break;
}
```

Comment: i should place it at where? inside my <a href?

Comment: in the top of ur php file. and in ur a tag ur href should be href='login.php?fn=handleLogin'